# ListView is expanding the width of my widgets

Tags: flutter

It seems like `ListView` stretches the width of its children to 100% screen width.

For example, despite explicitly setting the width in the example below, the width is stretched.

```
ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    width: 120,
                    child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        width: 100,
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.red),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: 3,
              )
```

The only way I have avoided this problem has been to wrap the returned widgets in a `Row`, but I would prefer to avoid that if possible (don't want to clutter the code).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wrap your `SizedBox` inside `Align`, `Center` or `UnconstrainedBox` widgets.

Check more info here `Layout Behavior` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html